# Show $\exists$ $b(\neq a)\in [0,1] $ $s.t. \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=2$ for this function

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Differentiable function, $f(x)$ satisfying the properties $(1)$ and $(2)$ on the $[0,1]$.
Show  $\exists$ $b(\neq a)\in [0,1] $ $s.t. \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=2$

- $(1)$ $f(1)-f(0) =2$ and $f(0)=1$
- $(2)$ $\exists$ $a $ $s.t. f'(a) \neq 2$

$pf)$ From the conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$ we would get the below results.

$f'(x) \neq 2$ on the $[0,1]$, We could say $f(x) \neq 2x+1$ at the $x=a$ from the $(2)$. Clearly $f(1)=3$

Without loss of generality, Say the $f(a)  > 2a+1$.

By Mean value thm, $\exists t_1 \in (0,a)$ and $t_2 \in (a,1)$ $s.t.$ $ f'(t_1) = \frac{f(a)-f(0)}{a} >2$ and $f'(t_2) = \frac{f(1)-f(a)}{1-a} <2$

By Darboux (intermediate value) thm, $\exists$ $c\in (t_1,a)$ or $(t_2,a)$ $s.t.$ $f'(c)=2$. $(*)$

Suppose $\not\exists$ $b(\neq a)\in [0,1] $ $s.t. \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} =2$. Hence by M.V.T  $f'(x) \neq 2$ whatever on the interval $(0,a)$ or $(a,1)$ is.

But this is contradiction with the $(*)$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Instead of using symbols and abbreviations, please try writing coherent and grammatically correct sentences. Right now I find this very hard to read.

Comment: "$f'(x) \neq 2$ on the $[0,1]$, We could say $f(x) \neq 2x+1$ at the $x=a$ from the $(2)$": This is not  valid argument. We can have $f'(a) \neq 2$ but $f(a)=2a+1$.

Comment: @Kechang lee. I can't sure I understood exactly what you meant.  But in my opinion you just proved the case only for the $ f(a) \neq 2a+1$. You also need to show the case for $f(a) = 2a+1$.

Comment: It seems the assumption $f(0)=1$ is irrelevant. $a=0$ and $b=1$ satisfy your claim. Unless you restrict to $0<a,b<1.$